# what is a free PDF create library for asp.net

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to create some reports on my asp.net website in PDF format. I need a way to do this easy. I am not using fancy text directions or things like that. What do you recommand I should choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is free.

However, any PDF library will require you to define fonts etc.

Comment: I am also open to any other solution like DOC to PDF. Do you think that could be faster? I would also like it not to have any banners in the generated pdf

Comment: @Ryan - how will such a transform make anything faster? Even for DOCs you need to specify things like fonts. And iTextSharp will not have banners, since it is _free_.

Comment: iTextSharp (from version 5) is AGPLed. If you're going to use it commercially, you either have to pay for a license or license your source under the GPL. you might want to check out, PDFSharp, PDFclown or PDFJet open source edition if you feel that is unacceptable